# Postgresql: "CASE" based on another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `stops_jena` which has stops in it (and every stop only appears once) and `trips_clean` which has the same stops in it, but many times. There is also a column called `vehicle` with three different values.
For every stop, I want a column that says `true` if the vehicle for this stop is 'bus'.

[picture of stops_jena](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZY2m.png)

```
WITH trips_stops_bus as (
  SELECT DISTINCT stop_name as stop
    FROM hafas.trips_clean
    WHERE hafas.trips_clean.vehicle = 'bus'
)

SELECT
    DISTINCT stops_jena.stop_name,
    case when stops_jena.stop_name = trips_stops_bus.stop then 'true' else 'false' end as bus   
FROM hafas.stops_jena, trips_stops_bus
ORDER BY stops_jena.stop_name
```

This is my query, but it gives a stop two times column bus is true [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVUEz.png)

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Could you give me an example for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the IN-conditon, so the stops only appear once:

```
 WITH trips_stops_bus as (
SELECT DISTINCT stop_name as stop
FROM hafas.trips_clean
WHERE hafas.trips_clean.vehicle = 'bus'
    )

SELECT
    DISTINCT stops_jena.stop_name,
    case when stops_jena.stop_name IN (SELECT stop from trips_stops_bus) then 'true' else 'false' end as bus 'false' end as bus   
FROM hafas.stops_jena, trips_stops_bus
ORDER BY stops_jena.stop_name
```